# Pegar o id do valor máximo

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Em uma tabela Mysql

```
id valor
1    5
2    15
3    7
```

Quero pegar o valor do "id" que tem maior valor no campo valor. Quero que me retorne neste caso o valor 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordene o resultado pelo valor DESC e limite a 1:

```
SELECT
    id
FROM tabela
ORDER BY valor DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Correto. estava tentando select id from tabela where MAX(valor);